# Whay ionCube loader enabled on cli not on web on osX EL-CAPITAN?

Tags: php, nginx, module

First of all I have added a `phpinfo();` file to see where `php.ini` for web resides. When I call that phpinfo path in localhost it prints out:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

I have put the below line in above conf file:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.26_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ioncube_loader_dar_5.6.so"
```

Now when I restart `nginx` and type `php -v` output says `ionCube` is enabled:

```
PHP 5.6.26 (cli) (built: Sep 25 2016 21:03:19)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v6.0.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
```

It seems that it is enabled on CLI not on web. But as I have shown above phpinfo() gives the same path for file configuration.

phpinfo file also says the same extension dir:

```
extension_dir   /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.26_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
```

I could that happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart `php-fpm` too in order for configuration to get applied:

```
$ sudo  brew services restart php56
```

Hope this helps to others and save sometime.